# Android: text in TextView won't fill all the available space

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in android but the text won't wrap consistently and properly.

In this first image:

[image: first image]

The word "little" clearly has enough space to populate the first line. However, it decides to get pushed off into the second line.
If I make the text of the body shorter though,

[image: second image]

You can see that it does properly fill that space.

How do I make it that the textview is consistent? Either scenario one or two is fine, but it needs to stay the same regardless of the length of the body.

This is my current code. 
I have tried messing with gravity and alignment but no success.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_body_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_text_size" />
```

Thanks!
(I apologize for not being able to embed the images; my reputation is not high enough)

Edit:
This seems to only be a problem in the emulator. When I load the app onto my phone, I can't duplicate this problem. As such, a solution is no longer necessary.

Comment: Please share your xml code!

Comment: Just for test, please remove alignRight and AlignEnd, would be there any difference?

Comment: @F.sh There is no difference. The aligns were added as an attempt to try to fix it but to no avail.

Comment: Do you want to justify the text from both sides?

Comment: @F.sh Just left justified is fine for my purposes.

Comment: What will happen if you go landscape? Can you share a screenshut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was caused by android:breakStrategy. Setting it to simple fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using LinearLayout with orientation="vertical". and set each text view width to "match_parent". Something like this :

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="16dp"
  >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_body_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="little"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/review_body_shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="princess"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

< /LinearLayout>

Comment: As per your suggestion, I wrapped the textview in a linearlayout of your settings. Still doesn't work.

Comment: set the gravity = "center_horizontal"